# I've been told that functions no need returns can be called without "()" sometimes, Is that right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

some jquery code like:

```
$("#buy_price").blur(function(){
    price_num;
});

$("#buy_num").blur(function(){
    price_num;
});

function price_num() {
    var price = $("#buy_price").val();
    var num = $("#buy_num").val();
    $("#buy_result").html(price*num);
};
```

can anyone tell me if it's right or not for sure?

Comment: No you have to add () that the compiler know its a function call

Comment: Eveb if thats so... Why would u want to call a function like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

better to use this way:

```
$("#buy_price, #buy_num").blur(price_num);
```

short and simple.

because `price_num` is a function itself then you can call it in the callback function of the bound event or you have to put `() parenthesis` there:

```
$("#buy_price, #buy_num").blur(function(){
    price_num();
});  //------^^----if this way then its needed for sure.
```

Answer (score 3):

No.

If you want to call a function, you can either:

1. Use `()`.
2. Instruct another function to call it.

The return value is irrelevant.

In this example:

```
$("#buy_price").blur(function(){
    price_num;
});
```

- The anonymous function is will be called by another function when the `blur` event occurs
- The `price_num` function won't be called at all because neither of the two conditions apply

However, if you were to:

```
$("#buy_price").blur(price_num);
```

Then `price_num` would be called by another function when the `blur` event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This is not (entirely) true. The person that told you that probably got confused  by a particular way of creating objects using the new operator.

This is valid and both statement will create an object as expected:

```
var a = new SomeFunction();
var b = new SomeFunction;
```

However, you can't call functions like that, as you are just returning the function to no-where.

```
myFunction; // Does nothing
```

Is exactly the same as these

```
42;
"Jsjsknsdjdj";
4 == 8;
```

All of these are just ignored because their value is not assigned to anything.

I'd recommend to always use `()` as it makes it clear when you read the code that a function call is being made, even when creating objects.